# Why are these characters printing at the start of putStrLn

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand the Tic Tac Toe game code from Programming In Haskell by G. Hutton.
The code is in the file tictactoe.hs. On Windows it generates these characters (←[2J←[1;1H) at the beginning of displaying the game grid. It doesn't happen on Ubuntu.

```
←[2J←[1;1H   |   |
   |   |  
   |   |
 -----------
   |   |
   |   |
   |   |
 -----------
   |   |
   |   |
   |   |
```

It seems to occur in this function

```
 putGrid :: Grid -> IO ()
 putGrid =
   putStrLn . unlines . concat . interleave bar . map showRow
   where bar = [replicate ((size*4)-1) '-']
```

Full code for the game is available here
[https://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/pih.html](https://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/%7Epszgmh/pih.html)

Comment: Likely these are ANSI terminal characters, but you are using a terminal that does not "understand' ANSI control characters.

Comment: What terminal are you using? MS Powershell has problems with ANSI. Also are you running in GHCi?

Comment: I have run it in ghci and as an executable from DOS & powershell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are [*ANSI escape codes* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSIsection). If you run this in a terminal that supports ANSI escape quotes, these can change how the characters will be printed: for example in boldface, in a different color etc.

The `←[2J` is what the terminal makes out of `"\ESC[2J"`, and this will clear the screan, whereas the `←[1;1H` will move the cursor to the top left corner, as is specied on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences):

|  | Abbr | Name | Effect |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (…) | (…) | (…) | (…) |
| `CSI n ; m H` | `CUP` | Cursor Position | **Moves the cursor to row *`n`*, column *`m`***. The values are 1-based, and default to 1 (top left corner) if omitted. A sequence such as `CSI ;5H` is a synonym for `CSI 1;5H` as well as `CSI 17;H` is the same as `CSI 17H` and `CSI 17;1H`. |
| `CSI n J` | `ED` | Erase in Display | Clears part of the screen. If n is 0 (or missing), clear from cursor to end of screen. If n is 1, clear from cursor to beginning of the screen. **If n is 2, clear entire screen** (and moves cursor to upper left on DOS ANSI.SYS). If n is 3, clear entire screen and delete all lines saved in the scrollback buffer (this feature was added for xterm and is supported by other terminal applications). |
| (…) | (…) | (…) | (…) |

This is thus used to "refresh" the screen with the new state of the game. In order to render this properly, you will need to use a terminal that will "understand" these sequences, and also implement these properly.

Answer (score 1):

The functions *`run, play :: ... -> ... -> IO ()`* (from Chapter 11) are the ones which invoke "screen utilities" `cls` ("clear screen") and `goto` ("go to position on screen") which do that.

You are referring to a copyrighted material so it is impossible to include full code  here. But you can find `cls` definition in the book's Chapter 10 where you will see its source code that prints that ANSI control sequence to clear the screen on ANSI-supporting terminals. The second escape sequence is surely generated by the `goto (1,1)` call in `run` (it also appears in `play`).

Comment: There is no copyright problem with quoting a brief extract from a book provided that on balance it is done for the purpose of scholarship, does not harm the commercial sale of the book and is not copied for a commercial purpose. https://www.copyright.gov/fair-use/more-info.html

Comment: @PaulJohnson thanks, but I'm not a copyright scholar / lawyer. :) So I just avoid copying the code altogether. In any case I've described exactly what it says and does.